Alfa 7961 WiFi NIC working on pi 3/4 but not pi5 w/ ubuntu 24.04
I have a fleet of raspis that I use as test wireless clients.  I use a the alfa 7961 wireless NIC in these devices and this has worked well across pi 3 and pi 4 devices.  I just got a pi 5 and I am seeing issues with this NIC. Below is a dmesg snip below of the events following connection of the device to the pi 5.
[  240.319373] usb 3-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci-hcd
[  240.333176] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0e8d, idProduct=7961, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  240.333185] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=6, Product=7, SerialNumber=8
[  240.333189] usb 3-1: Product: Wireless_Device
[  240.333193] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: MediaTek Inc.
[  240.333196] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 000000000
[  240.361608] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[  240.376614] Bluetooth: hci1: HW/SW Version: 0x008a008a, Build Time: 20220908211234
[  251.125081] Bluetooth: hci1: Execution of wmt command timed out
[  251.131044] Bluetooth: hci1: Failed to send wmt patch dwnld (-110)
[  251.137333] Bluetooth: hci1: Failed to set up firmware (-110)
[  251.143118] Bluetooth: hci1: HCI Enhanced Setup Synchronous Connection command is advertised, but not supported.
[  256.756976] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  262.388838] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  262.596805] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 2, error -62
[  268.020719] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  273.652602] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
.
repeat and increment address...
.
[  644.543801] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 45, error -62
[  649.967753] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  655.599681] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  655.807655] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 46, error -62
[  655.821757] usb usb3-port1: attempt power cycle

When the pi is in this state, lsusb hangs and does not return output until I disconnect the device, after which it returns output in a second or two listing only the hubs. lshw does not show the device either.  When testing other devices such as a wired USB NIC, Yubikey, keyboard...anything else I have on hand, I see them with lsusb with no issues and I get no addressing errors in dmesg.
In poking around, I have found suggestions that the "not accepting address" issue could be power draw related.  Unfortunately, I see the same issue when connecting the NIC via a powered USB hub, and this same NIC(not just same model, same physical unit) works flawlessly on a pi3/pi4 with the same image.
My image does contain the following two firmware files for this device, both in /lib/firmware/mediatek/
BT_RAM_CODE_MT7961_1_2_hdr.bin
WIFI_MT7961_patch_mcu_1_2_hdr.bin
Any suggestions are appreciated, and of course, I am happy to provide any additional info.
